# Spring Thymeleaf - Invalid property of bean class error

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying a simple drop down menu, where I populate it with objects from a `List`.

It returns this error:

> Invalid property 'tests' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'tests' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

I've followed some other tutorials and posts on SO, but still nothing. What am I missing to make this work?

Here is the HTML and controller class:

```
<body>
        <form th:object="${tests}" method='post'>
                <label>Select test</label> 
                <select th:field="${tests}">
                    <option 

                    th:each="test : ${tests}"
                    value="${test}"
                    th:text="${test}"

                    ></option>
                </select>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>
</body>
```

```
@Controller
public class TeacherController {

    TestController testcont = TestController.getInstance();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Teacher", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ModelAttribute("tests")
    //@GetMapping("/currentTestOptions")
    public String currentTestOptions(Model model) {

        for(Test test : testcont.showAllTests()) {
            model.addAttribute(test.toString(), test);
            return test.getName();
        }
        return "";
        //return "currentTestOptions";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have doesn't really make sense.

1. When you have a `th:object"${tests}"`, the expression `*{tests}` means `tests.getTests()`. (Which I don't think is a valid call because `test` is a `List<Test>` according to your code.)
2. In addition, all elements with the prefix `th:` have to be valid expressions.  You have a couple that aren't valid: `th:value="test"` and `th:text="test.getName"` should be `value="test"` and `th:text="${test.name}"` respectively.
3. You can't use a `List<>` as a form backing object.

Something like this should work, however you'll have to change your backing object if you want to get the form submission working.

```
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <label>Select test</label> 

    <select>
      <option
        th:each="test : ${tests}"
        value="test"
        th:text="${test.name}" />
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! What do you suggest in my case I change for the form backing object?

I was of the impression that one could pass a List, and then iterate it inside with the th:each.

Perhaps iterate through the objects in the List, and do a model.addAttribute("test", test);    for each individual test inside the List<Test>?

Comment: I updated my OP with some edited code. This version returns only the 1st object "Test1" in the List, so I need to iterate model.addAttribute for all tests with unique "labels" in some way?

Comment: No, you can add a list to the model fine, and loop over it in a th:each.  You just can't use a list as a form's th:object.